# Interface Injection beans.xml

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I am a bit new to springs and i am working on a springs3 MVC project. I have read about spring IoC and DI. Basically it supports constructor and setter DI. but i want to use an interface injection. I did search the entire google, gone through various examples but couldn't find any convincing example.

I have a `Interface` say `IntA` and its implementing `class IntAImpl`. i want to define its relation in `beans.xml`, like `IntA A = new IntAImpl();` and then i can inject `bean IntA` directly.

Any idea on this ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
@Autowired(value = "intA")
public class IntAImpl implements IntA {
}
```

Comment: how can i use this in other classes ?? i have a service class, where i instantiate IntA, how can i define this relation ?? and what about beans.xml ?? are there no changes to it ??

Comment: Wire it into every class that needs it.  You have to tell your app context XML to use context configuration scanning.  This is the newer annotation style for autowiring.  App context XML is Spring 1.0; now you have a choice.  If you call new, that instance is not under Spring's control.  You have to auto wire it and let Spring bean factory instantiate it.

Comment: ok i didnt knew that. I wasnt aware aware of this pattern of autowiring.

Answer (score 0):

Well i got it for what i was searching...
I have 3 classes as `IntA, IntAImpl, and Service` (as name suggest, `IntA` is an `interface`, `IntAImpl` is its implementing class and `service` class calls to `IntA` class method)

I created a `bean` for `IntAImpl` in `beans.xml`.
Then i injected the bean in `IntA` in my service class, like this

`IntA = (IntA)context.getBean("IntAImpl");`

my `beans.xml` is like this

`<bean id="IntAImpl" class="com.IntAImpl" autowire="byType"></bean>`

So this is how i achieved interface injection

(May b my question could have been misleading, sorry for that
)

Comment: Very good, but you're still working too hard.  Your service should not have to ask the context to getBean for you; it will do it if you auto wire it.  Less code, more Spring.

Comment: will it work if i autowire it ?? i think autowiring by type will work though

Comment: Auto wire it by name would be my preference.